# Is there a file for ip neigh show

Tags: ip, iproute, arp

I am looking for the file containing the output of `ip neigh show` command. I need the file as I can't invoke command and redirect as per requirement. The closest thing I found is the file `/proc/net/arp`. It contains almost the same IP-MAC entries but in a different format. Do there exist any file containing the same info which is displayed by `ip neigh show`?

Comment: Is it home work? It seems that you are doing well. Read the question again, then ask the teacher. As this seems like the correct answer.

Comment: No. its not a homework. I wrote a program to maintain ip-mac mappings dynamically as they may change using inotify-hooks. I require the output of ip neigh show. currently I am using arp table but it will be great if there exists something more precise to ip neigh show.

Comment: Then it would be easier to update your code to work with `/proc/net/arp` instead of trying to adjust it to `ip neight sh` output

Comment: Tell us what tools you have, what you are trying to do, what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the source code](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/ip/ipneigh.c), `ip neigh show` output is based on [`rtnetlink` messages from the kernel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html).

See [`netlink(7)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) for an example on how to operate a (rt)netlink socket, and the above-mentioned `rtnetlink(7)` man page for the necessary constants. I guess you'd want a `RTM_GETNEIGH` message.

Comment: Seems like there is no direct way. Thanks :)